# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments

I need help with my project please. I don't really have a lot to say other than that I'm trying to add payment gateway to my android app using stripe. I followed the [documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment). Towards the end where I have to test everything my app crashes and I get this error message [image: error message] I am almost done with this but this is the only thing in my way. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
//My code is here

private void startCheckout() {
        // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the sample server's /create-payment-intent endpoint.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        String json = "{"
                + "\"currency\":\"usd\","
                + "\"items\":["
                + "{\"id\":\"photo_subscription\"}"
                + "]"
                + "}";
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        httpClient.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new PayCallback(this));


        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayAlert(@NonNull String title,
                              @Nullable String message,
                              boolean restartDemo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message);
        if (restartDemo) {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Restart demo",
                    (DialogInterface dialog, int index) -> {
                        CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
                        cardInputWidget.clear();
                        startCheckout();
                    });
        } else {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        }
        builder.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Handle the result of stripe.confirmPayment
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(this));
    }

    private void onPaymentSuccess(@NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
                Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
                type
        );

        // The response from the server includes the Stripe publishable key and
        // PaymentIntent details.
        // For added security, our sample app gets the publishable key from the server
        String stripePublishableKey = responseMap.get("publishableKey");
        paymentIntentClientSecret = responseMap.get("clientSecret");

        // Configure the SDK with your Stripe publishable key so that it can make requests to the Stripe API
        stripe = new Stripe(
                getApplicationContext(),
                Objects.requireNonNull(stripePublishableKey)
        );
    }

    private static final class PayCallback implements Callback {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;

        PayCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity, "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity, "Error: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                );
            } else {
                activity.onPaymentSuccess(response);
            }

        }
    }

    private static final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;

        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment completed",
                        gson.toJson(paymentIntent),
                        true
                );
            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                // Payment failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment failed",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(paymentIntent.getLastPaymentError()).getMessage(),
                        false
                );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Payment request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
            activity.displayAlert("Error", e.toString(), false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  ok I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

int this line

```
  Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
                Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
                type
        );
```

you shold pass a json Object not a String, use GSON to fix it
something like that :

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Foo f = g.fromJson(jsonString, bar.class)
```

Comment: thanks for replying. how can i use Gson to fix t. How should that look?

Comment: can you help me? how can I fix this. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: where did bar.class come from? and where did the variable Foo come from I'm confused

Comment: Please respond I need help. No one is responding but you.